# this code is not running IE11

Tags: javascript

**this code is not running IE11 giving error:SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference
File: result.html, Line: 7, Column: 1 ,but this code is smoothly running in ie8.I want to run it IE11 browser.If code is wrong why it is runing without any error in IE8.What necessary changes are required in code or IE11 browser setting to run this code?I am again confirming that this same code is running smoothly IE8 browser,How is it possible? **

```html
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<script>
function ff()
{
document.getElementById('error').style.visibility="visible";
var rollno8=new Array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10');
var studentname8=new Array('ARUP DEY','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');
var fathersname8=new Array('DULAL CH. DEY','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');
var studentmarks8=new Array('50','60','55','65','70','74','75','52','45','89');
var m=document.getElementById('rollnumber').value;
var errormessage=document.getElementById('showerrormessage');
if(m=="")
{
document.getElementById('showerrormessage').style.visibility="visible";
errormessage.innerHTML="PLEASE PROVIDE YOUR ROLL NUMBER";
}

else
{
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
var student_name=document.getElementById('studentname');
var student_fname=document.getElementById('studentfname');
var student_rollnumber=document.getElementById('studentno');
var student_marks=document.getElementById('studentmarks');
var student_status=document.getElementById('studentstatus');
var a=studentname8[i];
var b=rollno8[i];
var c=fathersname8[i];
var d=studentmarks8[i];
if(m==b)
{
document.getElementById('error').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('getresult').style.visibility="visible";
student_name.innerHTML=a;
student_rollnumber.innerHTML=b;
student_fname.innerHTML=c;
student_marks.innerHTML=d;
if(d>=50)
{
student_status.innerHTML="PASS";
}
else
{
student_status.innerHTML="FAILED";
}
}

else
{
var ok=1;
}

}

if(ok==1)
{
document.getElementById('showerrormessage').style.visibility="visible";
errormessage.innerHTML="THIS ROLL NUMBER DOES NOT EXIST";
}

}
}


function resetMyResult()
{
document.getElementById('getresult').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('showerrormessage').style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
<form name="result">
<table align="center"style="border-color:black"border="2px"name="showmyresultform">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#cceecc;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">ROLL NUMBER</TD>
<TD style="background-color:#cceecc"><INPUT TYPE="TEXT"name="rollnumber"value=""size="20"maxlength="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#cceecc"align="center"><input type="button"value="SUBMIT"style="background-color:green"onclick="ff()">
<input type="reset"value="RESET"style="background-color:green"onClick="resetMyResult()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<form name="getresult"style="visibility:hidden">
<table style="border-color:black"border="2px"name="showmyresult"align="center">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">STUDENT'S NAME :</td><td><div id="studentname"style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold"align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">FATHER'S NAME :</td><td><div id="studentfname"style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold"align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">ROLL NO. :</td><td><div id="studentno"style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold"align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">MARKS OBTAINED :</td><td><div id="studentmarks"style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold"align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">STATUS :</td><td><div id="studentstatus"style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold"align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"align="center"><div id="showprint"><input type="button"value="PRINT"onClick="print()"style="background-color:#ccffff;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:black"></div>
</table>
</form>
<form name="error">
<table  align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="showerrormessage"style="background-color:;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:RED" align="center"value=""></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: If you could, move your JavaScript to the very bottom in the body or place it inside a document.onload, the fact is that your element node error doesn't exist when you define your function ff()

Comment: @ThiagoMelo It doesn't make any difference when the function is defined. It only matters when it's called.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues..

**a)** You are calling: `document.getElementById('error')` but you really don't have any element with id equaling to `error`. What you have in DOM is: `<form name="error">`.

Change the code to: `document.getElementsByName('error')[0].style.visibility="visible";`

**b)** The same thing with `document.getElementById('rollnumber').value`. Change the `<INPUT TYPE="TEXT"name="rollnumber"value=""size="20"maxlength="2">` to `<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="rollnumber" value="" size="20" maxlength="2">`

**c)** Please follow HTML5 standards about separating HTML attributes by space:

> ..there must be a space character separating the two

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags

The full code is here:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<script>
function ff()
{
document.getElementsByName('error')[0].style.visibility="visible";
var rollno8=new Array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10');
var studentname8=new Array('ARUP DEY','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');
var fathersname8=new Array('DULAL CH. DEY','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');
var studentmarks8=new Array('50','60','55','65','70','74','75','52','45','89');
var m=document.getElementById('rollnumber').value;
var errormessage=document.getElementById('showerrormessage');
if(m=="")
{
document.getElementById('showerrormessage').style.visibility="visible";
errormessage.innerHTML="PLEASE PROVIDE YOUR ROLL NUMBER";
}

else
{
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
var student_name=document.getElementById('studentname');
var student_fname=document.getElementById('studentfname');
var student_rollnumber=document.getElementById('studentno');
var student_marks=document.getElementById('studentmarks');
var student_status=document.getElementById('studentstatus');
var a=studentname8[i];
var b=rollno8[i];
var c=fathersname8[i];
var d=studentmarks8[i];
if(m==b)
{
document.getElementById('error').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('getresult').style.visibility="visible";
student_name.innerHTML=a;
student_rollnumber.innerHTML=b;
student_fname.innerHTML=c;
student_marks.innerHTML=d;
if(d>=50)
{
student_status.innerHTML="PASS";
}
else
{
student_status.innerHTML="FAILED";
}
}

else
{
var ok=1;
}

}

if(ok==1)
{
document.getElementById('showerrormessage').style.visibility="visible";
errormessage.innerHTML="THIS ROLL NUMBER DOES NOT EXIST";
}

}
}


function resetMyResult()
{
document.getElementById('getresult').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('showerrormessage').style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
<form name="result">
<table align="center" style="border-color:black" border="2px" name="showmyresultform">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#cceecc;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">ROLL NUMBER</TD>
<TD style="background-color:#cceecc"><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="rollnumber" value="" size="20" maxlength="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#cceecc" align="center"><input type="button" value="SUBMIT" style="background-color:green" onclick="ff()">
<input type="reset" value="RESET" style="background-color:green" onClick="resetMyResult()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<form name=" getresult" style="visibility:hidden">
<table style="border-color:black" border="2px" name="showmyresult" align="center">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">STUDENT'S NAME :</td><td><div id="studentname" style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold" align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">FATHER'S NAME :</td><td><div id="studentfname" style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold" align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">ROLL NO. :</td><td><div id="studentno" style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold" align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">MARKS OBTAINED :</td><td><div id="studentmarks" style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold" align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:white">STATUS :</td><td><div id="studentstatus" style="background-color:#cceecc;color:black;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold" align="center"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><div id="showprint"><input type="button" value="PRINT" onClick="print()" style="background-color:#ccffff;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:black"></div>
</table>
</form>
<form name="error">
<table  align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="showerrormessage" style="background-color:;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:RED" align="center" value=""></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you .tested your code ->when text box is blank giving result properly when submit button pressed, but reset button not working and other scripts are not working in IE11.Pl give your necessary advice.

Comment: @AKKAR You're welcome. I'm not sure why reset button is not working (can't look right now - I'm away of my pc) but it can be similar to points a) and b) mentioned above. Please check the error console (`Ctrl+Shift+K` in FireFox) and see the errors. Make sure you're not confusing element `name` with element's `id`.If this would be OK and you would still get errors, then perhaps double-check your code's business logic itself..

Comment: Dear Ivan Sivak and Mahesh Thakkar and others all of you are absolutely right.I just change all the 'name' into 'id' in my code thoroughly .Now the program is running without any error in IE11.A new conclusion has been drawn that IE8 browser can call name as id but IE11 can't.Thank you all of you.

Comment: @AKKAR You're welcome. IE8 uses `name` or `id` correctly, hence your issue is probably related to something else. Anyway glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access element by id e.g document.getElementById('error')
Please set id of the html element.

```
<form id="error">
```

you may need to apply this fix to many places in your html as you are assigning name to HTML element but accessing element using getElementById